# I can't factory reset my device

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, password, locked-out

I forgot my password and accidentally typed to many wrong passwords. I finally remembered it and manually changed it. But now it says that I need to reset the paasword via an email that I will get:

[image: screenshot] [image: screenshot]

It's been a long while and I don't have any email, not even in the spam. Please help I really need to reset my device!

Answer (score 0):

It is asked to you to reset your password from the Samsung site! Open a navigator (chrome, Firefox), go to [account.samsung.com](http://account.samsung.com) then reset your password using your actual Gmail email address.